# Copy a range into a single column - values only

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am trying to copy a range into a single column. The range is a mix of blank cells and cells with values.I only want to copy and paste the cells with values and I would it to find the first blank cell and want it to walk itself down the column from there.

The code I have right now (besides taking forever) pastes in the first row.

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("amount date").Select
For Row = 51 To 100
    For col = 2 To 1000
        If Cells(Row, col).Value <> "" Then
            Cells(Row, col).Copy
            Worksheets("sheet 2").Range("G" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next
Next

Do While Worksheets("sheet 2").Range("G" & i).Value <> ""
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `i` loop is outside your other loop so will never get updated.

Comment: Provide sample data, table struvture, so we can have some more specific advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will be a little faster (even though it seems to have been slow arriving).

```
Sub CopyRangeToSingleColumn()
    ' 20 Oct 2017

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastClm As Long
    Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
    Dim CellVal As Variant
    Dim Spike(), i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("amount date")
        With .UsedRange.Cells(.UsedRange.Cells.Count)
            LastRow = Application.Max(Application.Min(.Row, 100), 51)
            LastClm = .Column
        End With
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(51, "A"), .Cells(LastRow, LastClm))
    End With

    ReDim Spike(Rng.Cells.Count)
    For Each Cell In Rng
        CellVal = Trim(Cell.Value)               ' try to access the sheet less often
        If CellVal <> "" Then
            Spike(i) = CellVal
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Cell

    If i Then
        ReDim Preserve Spike(i)
        With Worksheets("sheet 2")
            LastRow = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row, 2)
            .Cells(LastRow, "G").Resize(UBound(Spike)).Value = Application.Transpose(Spike)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

The above code was modified to append the result to column G instead of over-writing existing cell values.

Comment: Hi, this is really quick! if I wanted multiple worksheet ranges to post into the same column UBound so it doesn't overwrite other worksheets how would you suggest i do that? @Variatus

Comment: I have modified the code to append the result to column G on Sheet 2 so that existing data in that column aren't over-written by subsequent runs of the procedure.

Comment: Brilliant!, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    i = 1

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("amount date").Select
    For r = 51 To 100
        For c = 2 To 1000
            If Cells(r, c).Value <> "" Then
                Cells(r, c).Copy
                Worksheets("sheet 2").Range("G" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If I try to paste another range from sheet "amount date 2" into the same column "G" finding the last blank row, after pasting the first range from sheet "amount date", will this just over wright the data from the first range "amount date" with data from "amount date 2"?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need copy the whole row into one cell, row by row? For each loop shall be faster. I guess, this should work

```
Sub RowToCell()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rRow As Range
Dim rRowNB As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim sVal As String


Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$B$51:$ALN$100") 'check this range
For Each rRow In rng.Rows
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rRowNB = rRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set rRowNB = Union(rRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas), rRow)
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each cl In rRowNB.Cells
             sVal = sVal & cl.Value
    Next cl
    Worksheets("sheet4").Range("G" & rRow.Row - 50).Value = sVal
    sVal = ""
Next rRow


End Sub
```

its quick for this range.

Comment: Hi, this is really quick! if I wanted multiple worksheet ranges to post into the same column UBound so it doesn't overwrite other worksheets how would you suggest i do that? @MarcinSzaleniec

Comment: you should replace Worksheets("sheet4").Range("G" & rRow.Row - 50).Value = sVal with worksheets("sheet4").Range("G" &  cells.rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)